# Show entire messages in Thunderbird 3's thread view?

Tags: email, thunderbird, preview

I recently upgraded to Thunderbird 3 on the Windows box which I am compelled to use for my email reading. I am loving the new feature which shows the body, title, and sender of all the messages in the thread in the message preview pane. The only thing that annoys me is that it only shows the first few hundred characters of the message body, not the entireity of it. Is there a setting which will tell it to show the entire messages, rather than truncating them where it sees fit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is currently not possible. There is a [Bug 510490](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=510490) on http://bugzilla.mozilla.org which talks about this request, but nothing has been decided yet on implementation.

Comment: Excellent! Very helpful answer!

Answer (score 0):

In order to extend Palmin's answer: The suggested solution is to use the add-on ["Thunderbird Conversations"](https://addons.thunderbird.net/de/thunderbird/addon/gmail-conversation-view/):

- [Bug 510490](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=510490) has been marked as duplicate of [Bug 677145](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=677145).
- [Bug 677145](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=677145) states that "Thunderbird Conversations" is a quasi-official add-on, and no need exists for making this a builtin feature.

As of Thunderbird 68, API changes seem to have required major changes to "Thunderbird Conversations". Due to a bug in Thunderbird that should be fixed in 68.8.0, using the add-on may result in read messages being randomly marked as unread again.